# Create a custom ID with Mgo

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm currently starting with GoLang and MongoDB.I'm writing a small web application, a blog to be more specific (which is like the first webapp I write when I try new languages). Everything works fine with MGO even if I had some troubles at first. But now I'd like to access each blog entry (articles will be referred as entries to stick with my models) separately. I could use the ObjectID in the url. But that's damn ugly. For example :
`mydomain.com/entries/543fd8940e82533995000002/`
That's not user friendly. I did a lot of research on the internet to find a suitable solution, because using any other database engine I could just use the id (and that would be fine).

Could someone help me with the creation of a custom (public) id which would auto-increment when I insert a new entry and that I could use in the url ?

Here is the code of my model for now :

```
package models

import (
    "time"

    "labix.org/v2/mgo"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
)

type (
    Entries []Entry
    Entry   struct {
        ID      bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        Title   string        `bson:"title"`
        Short   string        `bson:"short"`
        Content string        `bson:"content"`
        Posted  time.Time     `bson:"posted"`
    }
)

// Insert an entry to the database
func InsertEntry(database *mgo.Database, entry *Entry) error {
    entry.ID = bson.NewObjectId()
    return database.C("entries").Insert(entry)
}

// Find an entry by id
func GetEntryByID(database *mgo.Database, id string) (entry Entry, err error) {
    bid := bson.ObjectIdHex(id)
    err = database.C("entries").FindId(bid).One(&entry)
    return
}

// Retrieves all the entries
func AllEntries(database *mgo.Database) (entries Entries, err error) {
    err = database.C("entries").Find(nil).All(&entries)
    return
}

// Retrieve all the entries sorted by date.
func AllEntriesByDate(database *mgo.Database) (entries Entries, err error) {
    err = database.C("entries").Find(nil).Sort("-posted").All(&entries)
    return
}

// Counts all the entries.
func CountAllEntries(database *mgo.Database) (count int, err error) {
    count, err = database.C("entries").Find(nil).Count()
    return
}
```

Comment: You would have to maintain a separate collection that stores a field that increments as objects are added. That isn't as bad as it sounds as long as you write a function in Javascript that can handle this entirely on the Mongo side. Otherwise you'll have to retrieve it first from Go before incrementing it and using the incremented value for your document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know the _id is a mandatory field, that is automatically fill by the driver when you do not set it. This is the behavior that you have in your current application/code. You can find information about this type and its generation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

However, you can create your own _id and set the value to anything that makes sense for your business.

This is why I am do not understand the following statement:

> I did a lot of research on the internet to find a suitable solution, because using any other database engine I could just use the id (and that would be fine).

You can use any value you want as soon as it is unique for your collection.

About the auto-increment, MongoDB does not provide any auto increment field, so you have to implement it yourself, and call the increment from your application.

For example you create a new collection that contains your "sequences/counters": (showing shell commands not go)

```
{
  _id : "entry",
  sequence : 0
}
```

Then when you want an new id for your document you have first to update, with a findand modify the document you have created with a simple $inc operation

```
var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: "entry" },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );
```

You can then use the returned value into you new document as an _id.

This pattern is documented here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Of course you can use a Go implementation.. you just need to query the highest `id` value at app startup .. and keep track of it as items are inserted. It could be buggy though... better to let Mongo handle it.

Comment: @Depado The documentation for the [Query Apply method](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.Apply) shows how to implement a counter using mgo.